# Subclass-specific attributes in superclass __init__()

Tags: python, oop, subclass

I had a look around but couldn't find any answers. I have a slight issue - I have an abstract base class with a few abstract methods but also with several methods that are generic to all subclasses. Yet, in order to use these methods, I need to pass an subclass-specific attribute. This works fine, but I, of course, get warnings that the base class doesn't have the specific attribute:

```
Unresolved attribute reference 'c' for class 'Foo'
```

Let's assume I have this code:

```
from abc import ABC

class Foo(ABC):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def do_stuff(self):
        if hasattr(self, 'c'):
            return self.a * self.c
        elif hasattr(self, 'd'):
            return self.a + self.d


class Bar(Foo):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        super().__init__(a=a, b=b)
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
        
        self.some_dict = {}

    def get_value_from_dict(self):
        return self.some_dict[self.d]

class Baz(Foo):
    def __init__(self, a, b, d):
        super().__init__(a=a, b=b)
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.d = d
```

So, `Foo` is an abstract base class so it's never going to be called by itself but of course it's not nice to have these warnings. Yet if I add attribute `c` to the base class with a value of `None`, this results in an error because when subclass calls superclass' init, the value gets overwritten:

```
class Foo(ABC):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = None
```

If I change base class' init as shown above and then instantiate class `Bar` and call `get_value_from_dict()` I will get a `KeyError`, otherwise if I keep things as in the original example, then all works fine:

```
b = Bar(1, 2, 3)
b.do_stuff()
b.get_value_from_dict()
```

**EDIT:**
This is the actual code that I'm working with. This is what the `do_stuff` method in my example was meant to represent. Here `self.component` is a subclass-specific attribute and this generic method replaces erroneous values with a placeholder value.

There are several other generic methods in the base class that use `self.component` in a similar fashion.

```
class VariableImputer(ABC):
    def __init__(self, data: pd.DataFrame, deposit: str, output_loc: Optional[str] = None) -> None:
        self.data = data
        self.deposit = deposit
        self.output_loc = output_loc
        self.err_index: np.ndarray = np.full(self.data.shape[0], True)

    def _replace_erroneous_values(self):
        """
        Replace calculated component values with -99 for all rows indices of
        which are in self.err_index.
        """
        err_data = np.where(~self.err_index)[0]
        self.data.loc[err_data, self.component] = -99

class PopulateValue(VariableImputer):

    def __init__(self, data: pd.DataFrame, deposit: str, output_loc: Optional[str] = None):
        super().__init__(data=data, deposit=deposit, output_loc=output_loc)

        self.data = data
        self.deposit = deposit
        self.output_loc = output_loc

        self.component = ['porosity', 'sg']
```

But warnings are still there. What is the proper way to handle this situation?

Comment: You should add examples of how you instantiate things, call methods etc., and also the show errors themselves. This will minimize the effort for others trying to run your code.

Comment: @MikeRoll amended my post with additional information.

Comment: "This works fine, but I, of course, get warnings that the base class doesn't have the specific attribute" So, you just want to avoid the linter warnings on your IDE? Try just putting type annotations.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, well yes in a nutshell. I want to find out what I need to do differently to not have these warnings in the future.

Comment: You can turn off your linter.. But yeah, what IDE is this? PyCharm? Try putting type annotations in the class for the attributes.

Comment: Why are these attributes subclass-specific? This doesn't seem like a sensible way for a superclass and its subclasses to interact. You end up having to hardcode information about subclasses into the superclass `do_stuff` method.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica, This was a bad MRE that I came up with. I've added a snippet of one of generic methods that `do_stuff` method is meant to represent.

Comment: @pavel: So what happens if a subclass doesn't have `self.component`, then? Your original example had you switching based on different attributes defined by different subclasses, but that doesn't appear in your new example.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica, nothing really critical happens apart from linter showing warnings that the base class doesn't have `component` attribute.

Comment: ...but the method unconditionally tries to access `self.component`. How is "nothing really critical" going to happen? It's really unclear what's going on or why.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica, I've added more of the actual code. So here if I call an instance of a subclass, it all works without issues, except for the warnings by the linter. And only chance I see this going terribly wrong is if I could instantiate the base class, but of course I can't since it's an `ABC`.

Comment: This is getting really confusing. Your original code had attributes particular to *specific* subclasses, with the parent checking which attributes were present. Now it sounds like the parent is not using subclass-specific attributes at all; all subclasses have all attributes the parent is looking for.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica, yeah, I think I'm confusing everyone and myself. I better delete it and come back when I can ask the question properly, but since there answers, I can't delete it now.

Comment: If the superclass isn't checking for subclass-specific attributes, then it sounds like you might just need to name your parent something like `BaseFoo` or `AbstractFoo` or whatever pattern your IDE recognizes as "this thing is abstract". Inheriting from `ABC` does **not** make your class abstract - a class has to have abstract methods for the `abc` mechanism to consider it abstract (or abstract properties or other descriptors that report `True` from `__isabstractmethod__`).

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica, of course the base class has abstract methods, quite a few of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you don't have some `attr` in `Foo`. you still try to call it. the IDE will warn it.

there are two options:

1. turn off IDE lint check...(not good one.)
2. declare these `attr` as abstract attr.

```
pytho3 below

from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
class Foo(ABC):
    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def c(self):
        pass
```

Comment: Thanks! This actually works well for what I have because in two of subclasses I already have this additional attribute as a property.

Comment: This requires all concrete subclasses to implement a `c` property, though. Some subclasses don't have `c` in the question (and none of them have it as a property).

Comment: (Technically the check only checks that subclasses override `c` with *something*, not necessarily a property, but the override has to be at class level, not instance level.)

Comment: yeah, all subclass have to implement it. but this abstract property is not only the class level. :)

Answer (score 2):

So, if I do something like this, my linter stops complaining:

```
from abc import ABC


class Foo(ABC):
    a: int
    b: int
    c: int
    d: int
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def _do_stuff(self):
        if hasattr(self, 'c'):
            return self.a * self.c
        elif hasattr(self, 'd'):
            return self.a + self.d


class Bar(Foo):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        super().__init__(a=a, b=b)
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c


class Baz(Foo):
    def __init__(self, a, b, d):
        super().__init__(a=a, b=b)
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.d = d
```

Another alternative, use a sentinel value instead of checking `hasattr`:

from abc import ABC

```
class Foo(ABC):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def _do_stuff(self):
        if self.c is not None:
            return self.a * self.c
        elif self.d is not None:
            return self.a + self.d
```

But overall, this seems like code smell to me. You are just avoiding the fundamental issue, that your method should probably not be implemented in `Foo`, rather, it should be an abstract method that is implemented in the subclasses.

Why not just

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class Foo(ABC):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    @abstractmethod
    def _do_stuff(self):
        ...

class Bar(Foo):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        super().__init__(a=a, b=b)
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
    def _do_stuff(self):
        return self.a * self.c


class Baz(Foo):
    def __init__(self, a, b, d):
        super().__init__(a=a, b=b)
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.d = d
    def _do_stuff(self):
        return self.a * self.d
```

that seems like the most sensible solution to me.

Comment: Well, that `do_stuff()` method was probably not a great example. In reality in my code there a few methods that check validity of supplied data based on values of subclass-specific attributes and these methods are very generic and I really don't want to replicate them in subclasses.